# change smtps port in Postfix

Tags: postfix

Is it possible in `Postfix` to specify a non-standard port for `smtps`?

Normally, `smtps` listens on standard port `465`. Standard port is good for publicly used server. But if a server is only intended for private use, non-standard port would be preferable.

`smtps` is enabled by uncommenting the line in `master.cf`. There seems to be however no option to specify the port number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write the port number instead of `smtps` in the `master.cf` file. See the `master(5)` man page for more information; it says:

> The host part (and colon) may be omitted. Either host or port may be given in symbolic form (host or service name) or in numeric form (IP address or port number).

So, the numeric form is accepted.

Also, do not forget to uncomment the `-o` lines following the line that initially had `smtps`: these are these lines which enable SMTPS instead of normal SMTP.